# Configure 2 MFA Additional authentication methods?

Tags: azure, adfs, multi-factor-authentication, adfs4.0

Is it possible to enable and use multiple MFA solutions.  For example,  is it possible to select both DUO and Azure MFA option in ADFS settings shown below and create a rule/policy that directs some group/users to use Azure MFA and another to use DUO?

[image: Additional AUthentication Methods]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in AD FS from Windows Server 2019 onwards as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/whats-new-active-directory-federation-services-windows-server#authenticationpolicy-capabilities

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/18531/adfs-2019-multiple-mfa-provider-selection-on-rp.html for claims rules examples.